# composer error = [RuntimeException] on windows 10

Tags: windows, composer-php

im rookie on composer. these are my scenario:
- composer installed with administrative permissions without problem in windows 10.
- composer v1.10.6 was setup on PHP version 5.6.40
- composer is running under cygwin64 terminal
- on cygdrive: 'cd c:/wamp64/www/dev0'
- on cygdrive: 'composer create-project laravel/laravel test0 --prefer -dist'

get error: [RuntimeException] Invalid working directory specified,  does not exist.

need help to assign working directory to composer on windows 10

Comment: Please share the **exact** command you are calling

Comment: I like questions to be asked explicitly.